# Transaction is 20x slower on production server

Tags: postgresql, performance

One my development server the test transaction (series of updates etc) runs in about 2 minutes. On the production server it's about 25 minutes.

The server reads the file and inserts records. It starts out fast but then goes slower and slower as it progresses. There is an aggregate table update for each record that gets inserted and it is that update that progressively slows down. That aggregate update does query the table being written to with the inserts.

The config is only different in max_worker_processes (development 8, prod 16), shared_buffers (dev 128MB, prod 512MB), wal_buffers (Dev 4MB, prod 16MB).

I've tried tweaking a few configs and also dumped the whole database and re-did initdb just in case it was not upgraded (to 9.6) correctly. Nothing's worked.

I'm hoping that someone with experience in this could tell me what to look for.

Edit: After receiving some comments I was able figure out what is going on and get a work around going, but I think there has to be a better way. Firstly what is happening is this:

At first there is no data in the table for the relevant index, postgresql works out this plan. Note that there is data in the table just not anything with the relevant "businessIdentifier" index or "transactionNumber".

```
 Aggregate  (cost=16.63..16.64 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..16.63 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using transactionlinedateindex on "transactionLine" ed  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((("businessIdentifier")::text = '36'::text) AND ("reconciliationNumber" = 4519))
         ->  Index Scan using transaction_pkey on transaction eh  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=9) (never executed)
               Index Cond: ((("businessIdentifier")::text = '36'::text) AND (("transactionNumber")::text = (ed."transactionNumber")::text))
               Filter: ("transactionStatus" = 'posted'::"transactionStatusItemType")
 Planning time: 0.915 ms
 Execution time: 0.100 ms
```

Then as data gets inserted it becomes a really bad plan. 474ms in this example. It needs to execute thousands of times depending on what is uploaded so 474ms is bad.

```
 Aggregate  (cost=16.44..16.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=474.222..474.222 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..16.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=474.218..474.218 rows=0 loops=1)
         Join Filter: ((eh."transactionNumber")::text = (ed."transactionNumber")::text)
         ->  Index Scan using transaction_pkey on transaction eh  (cost=0.29..8.11 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.023..0.408 rows=507 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (("businessIdentifier")::text = '37'::text)
               Filter: ("transactionStatus" = 'posted'::"transactionStatusItemType")
         ->  Index Scan using transactionlineprovdateindex on "transactionLine" ed  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=0.934..0.934 rows=0 loops=507)
               Index Cond: (("businessIdentifier")::text = '37'::text)
               Filter: ("reconciliationNumber" = 4519)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 2520
 Planning time: 0.848 ms
 Execution time: 474.278 ms
```

Vacuum analyze fixes it. But you cannot run Vacuum analyze until after the transaction is committed. After Vacuum analyze postgresql uses a different plan and it's back down to 0.1 ms.

```
 Aggregate  (cost=16.63..16.64 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.072..0.072 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..16.63 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.069..0.069 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using transactionlinedateindex on "transactionLine" ed  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=0.067..0.067 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((("businessIdentifier")::text = '37'::text) AND ("reconciliationNumber" = 4519))
         ->  Index Scan using transaction_pkey on transaction eh  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=9) (never executed)
               Index Cond: ((("businessIdentifier")::text = '37'::text) AND (("transactionNumber")::text = (ed."transactionNumber")::text))
               Filter: ("transactionStatus" = 'posted'::"transactionStatusItemType")
 Planning time: 1.134 ms
 Execution time: 0.141 ms
```

My work around is to commit after about 100 inserts and then run Vacuum analyze and then continue. The only problem is that if something in the remainder of the data fails and it's rolled back, there will still be 100 records inserted.

Is there a better way to handle this? Should I just upgrade to version 10 or 11 or postgresql and would that help?

Comment: Please show us the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for both queries.

Comment: Also check that the server is not busy doing something else and really has the memory and CPU promised by the config.

Comment: How big are the tables? Do they have appropriate indexes? How does the update work, by incrementing existing rows or by recalculating the totals? If performance degrades as data gets added it probably means the server has to scan the entire table to calculate the totals

Comment: I added the explain output as an editServer is not busy, has way, way over the promised memory.

Comment: 4ms doesn't seem slow to me.

Comment: `Execution time: 4.045 ms` how fast do you want?

Comment: The update queries the table which includes the inserted data. I've been thinking that perhaps the inserted data is stored in some way that is slower to access prior to transaction commit. But on the dev machine its 10x faster (actually not 20 just feels like it). I added the explain output as an edit. It's actually the explain output for the select used in the update which is the slow part. Server is not busy, has way, way over the promised memory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses (no pun intended). 4ms is not the actual time. It's more like 0.5 sec. Initially it goes fast but after about a thousand inserts it slows down. I had the server print something after each query. Also need to keep in mind that the explain is just on the select part of the query the full query is something like update... set date = select max date from... Man I'd be so happy with 4ms

Comment: Include the EXPLAIN that shows 0.5 sec

Comment: Ok I got the explain output on the slow query. Sorry I should have go that first time, I'm new to "explain" as I've never had to worry much about performance before.

Comment: "*Shared buffers prod 12MB*" - really? why is prod configured so much smaller? Even 128MB is rather small for a production server (but that's not your problem here). It seems that in Prod you simply have more rows in prod. The index scan on `transaction_pkey` returns 495 rows in prod, but just one row in dev. Which in turn makes the index scan on `transactionLine_pkey` more expensive. And the update on prod runs in less than a second, so I don't see where the " 25 minutes" come from.

Comment: Shared buffers in prod is 512MB, 12MB was a typo. I've been able get a work around and understand what's going on enough to give you all some decent info to work with. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> There is an aggregate table update for each record that gets inserted and it is that update that progressively slows down.

Here is an idea: Change the workflow to (1) import external data into a table, using COPY interface, (2) Index and ANALYZE that data, (3) run the final UPDATE with all required joins/groupings to do actual transformation and update the aggregate table.

All of that could be done in one, long transaction - if needed.

Only if the whole thing is locking some vital database objects for too long, you should consider splitting this into separate transactions / batches (processing data partitioned in some generic way, by date/time or by ID).

> But you cannot run Vacuum analyze until after the transaction is committed.

To get updated costs of query plan, you need only `ANALYZE` not `VACUUM`.

Comment: Thanks, filiprem. I put in an Analyze after some data get's inserted and it's fixed the problem. I've thought about changing the workflow, but I think I still have to do an update for each record most of the time and with it running in 0.14 ms now :) there is no need to change.